# Can C++ binary code become portable through a native C interface? What are the limitations?

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, compatibility, binary-compatibility

I often use the technique to wrap my high-performance C++ classes with a a thin C layer that I compile to shared libraries, and then load them in other programming languages, such as Python.

From my reading here and there, I understand that the only requirement for this to work, is to have the function interfaces *use only native types or structs of these types*. (so, `int` and `long`s, `float`, `double`, etc and their pointers of any rank).

**My question is: Assuming full [ABI compatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) between various compilers, is this the only requirement I have to fulfill to have full API compatibility with a shared library?**

Why can't C++ libraries be ported? Here's my understanding:

**Case 1:** Consider the type `std::string`. Internally it contains a `char*` null-terminated string, and a size integer. The C++ standard doesn't say which of these should come first (right?). Meaning that if I put `std::string` on a function interface, two different compilers may have them in different order, which will not work.

**Case 2:** Consider inheritance and vtables for a class with virtual methods. The C++ standard doesn't require any specific position/order for where vtable pointers have to go (right?). They could be at the beginning of the class before any other variable, and they could also be at the end, after all other member variables. So again, interfacing this class on a function will not be consistent.

**An additional question following my first one:** Doesn't this very problem happen also inside function calls? Or is it that nothing matters after it's compiled to binary, and types have no meaning anymore? Wouldn't RTTI elements cause problems, for example, if I put them in a C wrapper interface?

Comment: What do you mean with "the standard"? The language standards don't give you any ABI guarantees (almost). The ABI standards like Itanium do of course, including vtables etc. ABI compatibility between standard library types would be the domain of the concrete implementations.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Sure. The C++ standard doesn't have any ABI guarantees. That's part of my question. I'm sorry, I don't understand whether you're asking or making a statement.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the question *"Why can't C++ libraries be ported?"* If you are only looking at the language standards, that's an odd question because they don't cover ABI compatibility to begin with. Even the vtables are an implementation detail and need not exit. If we include the guarantees provided by the implementations, that statement is not really true, you *can* portably build and ship binaries (both libraries and executables) from C++ code for some given architecture, like your Linux's pre-built packages for x86_64.

Comment: @BaummitAugen "Why can't C++ libraries be ported" is not really an open question. I'm answering that below it, and checking whether my understanding is correct. Actually my question is only according to the C++ standard, not according to certain implementations.

Comment: Assuming the same calling convention is used, then the functions binary compatible between two compilers.

Comment: @TommyAndersen What do you mean by calling convention?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist The manner in which you pass parameters to a function, is the calling convention. For instance if you push the number of arguments first, and then push each argument. Or if some arguments are stored directly in registers, etc.

Comment: Maybe this is me being too bad at English again, I'll try again: In general, neither C nor C++ is portable in an ABI sense, each compiler can use its own size of `int`, `long` etc., they may even change that based on compilation settings. However, if we choose some target, both C and C++ are portable, e.g. by fixing all implementation defined stuff to gcc's choices (+ relevant standards) for x86_64 or whatever. So the premise of the question seems off already.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks. That helps actually. What about Windows? Do we have ABI compatibility between MSVC and MinGW, for example? And do we have binary compatibility between gcc and clang?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist The compilers of clang and gcc are binary compatible by default, however, libc++ and libstdc++ are not. So if you want to mix those, you'll need a wrapper, but clang can also use libstdc++. No idea about the Microsoft world.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Windows has some "ABI" compatibility in some few areas, due to COM, where pure virtual interfaces are requried to be laid out in a specific way. So a compiler for Windows would need to conform to this, in order to allow interacting with the Windows API.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I think I almost got my answer :)

Comment: gcc (specifically MinGW) is ABI compatible with MSVC when compiling C (but not C++).

Comment: Note that on posix-y platforms a C++ shared library can break another C++ shared library simply by being loaded to the same executable. This happens when the two libraries use different incompatible versions ot the c++ standard library, as e.g. happens with libstdc++.so.{5,6}. The same thing can in principle happen with C libraries but in practice it's very rare.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for the info. This helps, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why there is no C++ ABI, is partly because there is no C ABI. As stated by Bjarne Stroustrup ([source](http://www.stroustrup.com/slashdot_interview.html)):

> The technical hardest problem is probably the lack of a C++ binary interface (ABI). There is no C ABI either, but on most (all?) Unix platforms there is a dominant compiler and other compilers have had to conform to its calling conventions and structure layout rules - or become unused. In C++ there are more things that can vary - such as the layout of the virtual function table - and no vendor has created a C++ ABI by fiat by eliminating all competitors that did not conform. In the same way as it used to be impossible to link code from two different PC C compilers together, it is generally impossible to link the code from two different Unix C++ compilers together (unless there are compatibility switches).

The lack of an ABI gives more freedom to compiler implementations, and allows the languages to be spread to multiple different types of systems.

On Windows there are some platform specific dependencies that relies on the way the compiler outputs the result, one example comes from [COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485850(v=vs.85).aspx) where pure virtual interfaces are required to be laid out in a specific way. So on Windows most compilers will, at least agree on that.

The Windows API uses the [`stdcall`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#stdcall) calling convention, so when coding against the Windows API, there are a fixed set of rules for how to pass parameters to a function. But again this is system dependent, and there is nothing preventing you from writing a program that uses a different convention.

Comment: This clarifies stuff partially. Thanks! +1!

Comment: COM is a bit tricky; you can do COM from C which doesn't even have pure virtual interfaces. However, COM certainly is a _lot_ easier when the compiler has built-in support for it. Pretending that COM interfaces are C++ pure virtual interfaces is one possible way.